# Two ways to calculate the t statistic in the same publication

Tags: t-test, meta-analysis, effect-size

The What Works Clearinghouse (WWC) performed meta-analyses and the procedures are published in the WWC Procedures Handbook (4.1) https://ies.ed.gov/ncee/wwc/Docs/referenceresources/WWC-Procedures-Handbook-v4-1-508.pdf
In that Handbook, I found two formulas involving the t statistic but these two formulas are different, and I would like to understand why.

**WWC procedures**
To facilitate comparisons of findings across studies, the WWC computes the effetctsize and standard error associated with study findings on outcome measures.

ni = intervention student sample size
nc= control student sample size 
mi = mean of the outcome for the intervention group 
mc= mean of the outcome for the comparison group
s = pooled within-group SD of the outcome at student level
w = 1-$\frac{3}{(4(ni+nc)-9)}$

The basic formula for computing standardized mean difference follows :
$$
g= \frac{mi-mc}{s} \quad (1.1)
$$
Hedges’g corrected for a small-sample bias is the default effect size measure for continuous outcomes used in the WWC’s review
$$
g= w*\frac{mi-mc}{s} \quad (1.2) 
$$
and the standard error for the Hedges’ $g$ is
$$
SE(g)=w* \sqrt{1/ni+1/nc+\frac{g^2}{2ni+2nc}} \quad (2.2)
$$
When means or SD are not reported, the WWC compute Hedges’ g based on t test result (reported by the study authors)
$$
g=w*t*\sqrt{(1/ni+1/nc} (3.1)
$$
in other words, 
$$
t=\frac{g}{( w*\sqrt{(1/ni+1/nc)}} (3.2)
$$
and then we find the classic formula (3.2)+(1) :
$$
  t=\frac{(mi-mc)}{(s*(1/ni+1/nc)^{0.5})} \quad (4)
$$
To know the statistical significance of the estimate of the effects, the WWC will use the effect size and standard error formulas to calculate the t statistic corresponding to the effect size
$$
t=\frac{g}{(1/ni+1/nc+g^2/(2ni+2nc))^{0.5}} (5)
$$

---

**My questions**
We do not know which formula is used for $g$ in (5) : if $g$ is coming from (1.1), it seems to me that (5) could be interpreted as $t=g/SE(g)$, which looks like the z-score $z=g/SE(g)$ as suggested by BORENSTEIN (effect sizes based on means). If not, and if the idea is to divide Hedges’ $g$ (but, again, I’m not sure of this) by his standard error (2.2), then a factor $w$ is missing.
Anyway, I do not understand how to explain the difference between (3.2) and (5).

Comment: Nathalie I have tried to format your mathematically formulae using MathJax. Please check it as I think I may not have got some of the formulae translated correctly. I hope it is easy to see now how to edit any of my mistakes.

Comment: Ok, medewey, that sounds perfect except number 2.2 : the square root is the same as the denominator of equation 5 (that is 2ni+2nc is the denominator of g^2 only). Many thanks !

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Yes ! Its all right now ! Thanks